# Will installing mysqlnd break existing code in PHP which uses mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

I'm moving my code from using mysql in PHP to mysqli. In order to get the [mysqli get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) function to work I need to install mysqlnd as [said here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php). This involves removing the existing php-mysql extension, and now I just want to make sure (those of you who did this) that once I remove the mysql with:

```
yum remove php-mysql
```

and install mysqlnd with:

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

the other code (there's  a lot of existing codebase) that uses mysql will still work?

My PHP Version is 5.3.27

Comment: @CeesTimmerman mysqli also has prepared statements as far as I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to generally answer that NO it's not safe to just remove php-mysql and install php-mysqlnd, especially if you're not "a server guy". Because once I removed php-mysql I removed phpmyadmin along with it and that was quite a disaster.

I ended up (with help of Rackspace server guys) with upgrading my PHP to 5.4 (can't go to 5.5 yet until I convert all my code to use mysqli) and then manually forcing the install of `php54-mysqlnd-5.4.17-1.ius.el6.x86_64` (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/), because of the error while trying to do it "the normal way" `Error: php54-mysql conflicts with php54-mysqlnd-5.4.17-1.ius.el6.x86_64`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I know this is old, just came accross, but why is it a disaster to manually download and upload phpmyadmin? I'd use the fresh from their site package, they update and fix a lot.

Comment: This was a sysadmin failure - not a code failure.

In my experience, there have been no problems caused by upgrading. 

If you're on Debian an 'apt-get install php5-mysqlnd' works fine and doesn't break anything.

Comment: I would say that's not a problem with the libraries, but a mistake of the admin not understanding the packaging system or a fault in the package. If both php-mysql and php-mysqlnd packages have the same dependencies, including phpmyadmin, then one can simply install php-mysqlnd and resolve the obvious conflict (which leads to php-mysql being uninstalled). I just performed this on Ubuntu 14.04 without any issues.

Answer (score 7):

With both of `php-mysql` and `php-mysqlnd` you have `mysql`, `mysqli` and `PDO` drivers all together. If you just need `mysqli` driver you already have it with `php-mysql`.

However if you want migrate to MySQL native driver According to documentation you must pay attention to these:

> --The new mysqlnd library necessitates the use of MySQL 4.1's newer
> 41-byte password format. Continued use of the old 16-byte passwords
> will cause mysql_connect() and similar functions to emit the error,
> "mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication." The
>
> --new mysqlnd library does not read mysql configuration files
> (my.cnf/my.ini), as the older libmysqlclient library does. If your
> code relies on settings in the configuration file, you can load it
> explicitly with the mysqli_options() function. Note that this means
> the PDO specific constants PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_READ_DEFAULT_FILE and
> PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP are not defined if MySQL support in
> PDO is compiled with mysqlnd.

Generally you don't have any problem to migrate from MySQL driver to MySQL native driver. Also it recommended to use php-mysqlnd instead of  php-mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Also be aware of mysqlnd returning number as numbers, while libmysqlclient (php-mysql) returns all types as string.

So if you use `===`, it may give unexpected behavior.

Had a case with mysqlnd in the dev-envirement, and libmysqlclient in the production-envirement, got a few bugs where I compared a string value and an integer value, but on the dev server they was both integers.