# how can I mysqlnd work with php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqlnd

i use php 5.2 but it doesn't support mysqlnd. so I changed php with 5.3.7 but I can't handle it...what's wrong with it

version info

- OS window7
- PHP 5.3.7v
- Mysql 5.1.39
- Apache 2.2.14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable mysqlnd for php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the Php installation manual you will see that:

> Installation on Windows
>
> In the official PHP Windows distributions from 5.3 onwards, MySQL
>   Native Driver is enabled by default, so no additional configuration is
>   required to use it. All MySQL database extensions will use MySQL
>   Native Driver in this case.

So you just need to install php and it will be working already. Try to reinstall PHP from scratch if you manipulated it's configuration files too much and you should have no issues.