# How to update MySqli to php5-mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently started coding with Codeigniter, so fairly new, even to php.

I built my first app, installed it on server after Xampp. I got this error

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50542 Library:50626

After searching online I found that I need php5-mysqlnd. I found [this nice article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php) but don't know where all these processes are happening.

Is there a tool in Cpanel where all these codes for updating php5-mysqlnd are taking place?

All I know I have Linux hosting version 5.4.45 with Hostgator.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, I have just added the link  in question. Here it is too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I found another way to do it (not like the way that link said).

I was going through my CPanel and found an option to change my PHP version. I clicked and on next page it asked what all components I want to include, I couldn't believe "Mysqlnd" was one of them.

I changed it to 5.6 from 5.4.45. That's all it took.

Thanks a lot.