# I can not find a repository for CentOS 6.6 containing the PHP MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd)

Tags: php, mysql, driver, native, centos6

Recently I have decided to switch to the MySQL Native Driver for PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php

I am using CentOS 6.6 and I couldn't find a repository containing the php-mysqlnd. The default repositories does not include it. I do not want to recompile PHP from scratch since I have cPanel on top and I just don't want to mess up with it. Currently I just want to switch from php-mysql to php-mysqlnd and that's all.

What I have tried so far:

```
yum remove php-mysql
```

then

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

this has ended with:

```
No package php-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Then I have tried to add repositories like remi and webtatic. Neither of them worked.

Does any one knows a repository containing the php-mysqlnd?

Answer (score 1):

cpanel is too much altered, cannot be considered as CentOS anymore.

cpanel provides its own PHP stack, so none of the 3rd party repo will be able to help you.

You should contact cPanel support.

Comment: OK, but I have the same problem with another server on CentOS 6.6 with no panel on it and PHP 5.3.3 / MySQL 5.1.73. The main limitation is that I'm not able to upgrade the versions (I have some specific reasons not to do it) and basically I prefer not to recompile PHP. I saw here that some guys have done it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php even with older PHP version but strangely it does not work for me - all the repos I tried just do not contain the driver.

Comment: mysqlnd doesn't exists for 5.3.3, because at that time, it was not supported to build it as a shared extension, which is possible only since 5.3.9 (so PHP 5.4 stack usually provides both, and 5.5+ only  mysqlnd). See https://bugs.php.net/55609