# Mysql is not compiled with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, centos6

I am using php 5.3 Centos6. I have installed mysql. But when i see "configure command" in phpinfo, it shows `'--without-mysql'`.

How to add `'--with-mysql'` in PHP configuration file.

Comment: You don't add that flag in the PHP configuration, you should've done that when you were compiling PHP. You can re-compile it to include the MySQL stuff. But it's much easier to use a package manager like yum to install PHP though.

Comment: did you restart your httpd server after you did the make install?

Comment: Yes PHP 5.3.3. I have restarted many times. How can i recompile..i don't have original source code.

Answer (score 1):

You must install php-mysqlnd or php-mysqli extension. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13176783/6209665) for explanation.

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

Comment: I tried with same command. but i am getting error. "No package php-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do"

Answer (score 1):

The `--without-mysql` and `--with-mysql` refers to a compilation setting. There's a good chance you're installing pre-compiled binaries with the `yum` command.

To be clear: `--with-mysql` is not a php configuration setting but rather something that is done with the php source.

As @Andrew suggested it makes the most sense to install the `php-mysqlnd` extension. This is essentially a snippet of the php source with the `--with-mysql` directive given. (That last sentence is heavily paraphrased).

Comment: I tried with same command. but i am getting error. "No package php-mysqlnd available. Error: Nothing to do"

Comment: It looks like the package might be called `php-mysql`

Comment: You'll have to enable it too. Some package managers will do this based on scripts but I'm unsure of CentOS. Can you search for any occurrences of `mysql` in your php.ini file and post the results here?

Comment: michael, i have posted my phpinfo page output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for the php.ini file itself (not the whole thing, just search for any occurrences of `mysql`). You can find the location by running `php -i | grep php.ini`

Answer (score -1):

My phpinfo page is look like this,

```
./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu 
--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr --exec-
prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --
datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --
libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --
mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --cache-file=../config.cache --
with-libdir=lib64 --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-
dir=/etc/php.d --disable-debug --with-pic --disable-rpath --without-pear --with-
bz2 --with-exec-dir=/usr/bin --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --
with-xpm-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --without-gdbm --with-gettext --with-
gmp --with-iconv --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex=/usr --
with-zlib --with-layout=GNU --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-magic-quotes --
enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --with-
kerberos --enable-ucd-snmp-hack --enable-shmop --enable-calendar --without-
sqlite --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-xml --with-system-tzdata --with-
apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --without-mysql --without-gd --disable-dom --disable-dba --
without-unixODBC --disable-pdo --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter --
without-sqlite3 --disable-phar --disable-fileinfo --disable-json --without-
pspell --disable-wddx --without-curl --disable-posix --disable-sysvmsg --
disable-sysvshm --disable-sysvsem
```

Answer (score -1):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/usr' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-sqlite3=shared,/usr' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--without-readline' '--with-libedit' '--with-pspell=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--with-tidy=shared,/usr' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-intl=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr'
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead in Unknown on line 0
PATH => /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/usr/local/vivek/mysqlinstall/mysql5.6/bin/
_SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/usr/local/vivek/mysqlinstall/mysql5.6/bin/
```

Comment: Perfect, now what is inside these 3 files? `/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini`, `/etc/php.d/mysql.ini`, and `/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini`