# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::next_result()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, multiple-resultsets

I'm trying to loop through a stored procedure, called via prepared statement, in PHP. Hopefully it's not impossible. Here's my PHP code:

```
$database = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$stmt = $database->prepare("CALL thisShouldReturnEightResultSets (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

do {
    if ($res = $stmt->bind_result($myvar)) {
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo "*" . $myvar . "<br/>";
    } else {
        if ($stmt->errno) {
            echo "Store failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
} while ($stmt->next_result());
```

That should print like so:

```
* 4
* 16
* 7
etc...
```

... and then exit once it runs of out result sets. Instead I get:

```
* 4

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::next_result()
```

At first I tried *get_result* instead of *bind_result*, but that errored. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result) I found that I don't have the mysqlnd driver installed. Iworked around that with *bind_result*. Now I need a work around for *next_result* which I'm guessing is part of the mysqlnd driver as well. What are my options here? Tech notes:

```
PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11
```

Thanks.

Comment: `next_result` is only used when using `multi_query`.

Comment: You're not performing multiple queries, why do you think you need to use `next_result`?

Comment: There are multiple selects in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a prepared statement, since you don't have the MYSQLND driver. You'll have to do it the old fashioned way, with escaping.

```
$id = $database->real_escape_string($id);
if ($database->multi_query("CALL thisShouldReturnEightResultSets ('$id')")) {
    do {
        if ($result = $database->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                echo "*" . $row[0] . "<br/>";
            }
        }
    } while ($database->next_result());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Stored procedure being called has multiple selects in it. The code above would only print the '4' from the first select's result set.

Comment: I've changed the answer to show how to do it with `multi_query`.

Answer (score 0):

bindResult does not like multiple results.

Use get_result() then fetch_assoc and store in an array, 
Then use a foreach loop to output your results.

```
  $res = $stmt->get_result();
  $array[];

  while($x = $res->fetch_assoc()){
     $array[]=$x;

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php

Comment: Don't have the option to install it available on shared hosting. That's why I need another solution.