# PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES=false No longer forces PDO to return INTs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Since a couple of days I have one application (on a Clients server I do not have full access to yet) that refuses to obey the `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES=false` setting.

Code below should return `integer` (as it does on my own servers)

Yet on one server (I mailed them this testcode) it returns `string`

```
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='TABLES';");
$stmt->execute();
$tables = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<H1>" . gettype($tables['VERSION']) . "</H1>";
var_dump($tables);
```

Setting `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES=true` of course exhibits the same behaviour on my own servers, as PDO by default returns integers as strings.

But the application requires integers to be integers in PHP.

As said; I do not yet have access to that server. Any pointers though?

#### Update

I finally got some phpinfo()

MySQLND is (for unknown reason) now missing (it was there before as the application ran fine)

Have directed sys-admins to blogs on activating MySQLND (again)

[How to enable mysqlnd for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php/18329348)

Comment: What version of PHP are they running? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197041/1491895) says it requires PHP 5.3 with the MYSQLND driver.

Comment: Don't know the details yet. They claim they haven't changed anything; application ran fine for years. Hoping someone will copy/paste above code and experiences similar issue.

Comment: They always claim that. If the behavior changed, something must have changed.

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` on their server and compare it to yours.

Comment: I have finally seen a screenshot (argh!.. governments) of their phpInfo() **There is no MySQLND section**; Plenty of blogs on how to enable it; can't read anywhere how it could have been disabled. I know the Native Driver was there before, because the application does strict comparisons thus required Integers