# Undefined PHP functions that should be included

Tags: php

I'm working on a school project, and I have two identical databases on two different PCs. I'm running the same website, identical files, on each one.

On my laptop, the `mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)` function works perfectly, whereas on my desktop it returns an call to unidentified function error. Likewise, `mysqli_stmt_close()` works fine on my desktop, but not on my laptop.

I'm using `php 7.2.1` on my desktop, and `7.2.14` on my laptop, so these should be included...

Comment: What does the `php_info` return on each machine? What is the actual error message? `strtolower` has been around since PHP 4 so that being undefined should be the sign of a bigger issue

Comment: Turns out that I just spelled wrong, so strtolower works

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have mysqlnd installed/loaded whatever, you will get an undefined reference when trying to call `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` as according to the comment [here](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#113398). To get more info about how to install mysqlnd driver you can see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159518/how-to-enable-mysqlnd-for-php)